# How to enable bluetooth in my laptop

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Dell Vostro 2420, and I have installed Bluetooth software and it is coming in PC settings but it is blocked.

I am not able to turn ON it. Please help me.

Comment: give more details like your os which software you installed and exact error you are getting

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing what OS you are using I'm just guessing here, In Ubuntu **16.04** at the top of your desktop there should be a **Bluetooth** icon, right clicking on it will give you options to turn it **off** and **on**... and you can assess the Bluetooth settings as well

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth showing in your settings menu doesn't mean anything. It's possible that your hardware doesn't have bluetooth. Or check if there is a switch on your laptop, that switch controls your wifi and bluetooth on/off all together.

The same thing happens to my thinkpad t430, and it turmed out my laptop didn't come with bluetooth. Bummer.